# How to select a link in a page based on its href attribute, LinkText not working

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select a link based on the "href" attribute with an TextLink. I cant use the xpath here because the links keep moving around the page every time the page loads. Kindly advise

My HTML :

```
<li class="navw2">
<a href="/index/lobby.html">购彩大厅</a>
</li>
```

My CODE :

```
element=driver.findElement(By.LinkText("购彩大厅")).onlick();
```

Comment: An xpath would be `//a[text()='购彩大厅']`, the href also has nothing to do with the text, the text is in the anchor

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Hi , i use the same xpath as given but it's encounter error with NoElementFound .....

Comment: If there is a visible anchor with that text than the xpath would find it. You could try contains `"//a[contains(.,'购彩大厅')]"`

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham there is some issue reading the chinese words , as the chinese words become special characters although i change the text file into UTF-8

Comment: I use python but have you tried something like `\xe8\xb4\xad\xe5\xbd\xa9\xe5\xa4\xa7\xe5\x8e\x85'`? Obviously however you represent the same in java

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Hi , sorry that im not understand what you trying to describe on

Comment: A utf-8 encoded version of your string, your problem seems more an encoding than an xpath issue

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham What if i just call href with /index/lobby.html without contains chinese character , will its work ?

Comment: Is the href unique? If it is you can `//a[@href='/index/lobby.html']`

Answer (score 0):

Using x-path, try the following code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='navw2']/a"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding` is the issue here. Not the `Xpath`. Instead of using `LinkText` you can go ahead with any of the below options:-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='navw2']/a"));
element.click();
```

Or

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/index/lobby.html']"));
element.click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li > a"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this xpath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//li[@class='navw2']/a[contains(text(),'购彩大厅')]"));
element.click();
```

If there is possibility of having multiple links of the same type, you can use this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//li[@class='navw2']/a[contains(text(),'购彩大厅')]"));
elements.get(0).click();
```

Or

```
List<WebElement> elements =  driver.findElements(By.XPath("//li[@class='navw2']/a[@href='/index/lobby.html'  and contains(text(),'购彩大厅')]"));
elements.get(0).click();
```